# C++11 smart pointers and polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism, smart-pointers

I'm rewriting an application using c++11 smart pointers.

I have a base class:

```
class A {};
```

And a derived class:

```
class B : public A {
  public:
  int b;
};
```

I have another class containing a vector with either A or B objects:

```
class C {
  public:
  vector<shared_ptr<A>> v;
};
```

I have no problem constructing C with A (base class) objects but how can I fill it with B (derived class) objects?

I'm trying this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    v.push_back(make_shared<B>());
    v.back()->b = 1;
};
```

And the compiler returns:
error: ‘class A’ has no member named ‘b’

Comment: What are you trying to do? It sounds like treating A as polymorphic is a wrong idea, since you won't be making use of that.

Comment: It's not about smart pointers, you are using polymorphism incorrectly. Replace public b member with virtual function (probably, get and set functions).

Comment: I've simplified the classes. In their real form the polymorphism makes sense.

Comment: Then it sounds like the simplified example is not representative of the real problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> But how can I fill it with B (derived class) objects?

You are filling it with (pointers to) `B` objects. However, the pointers' static type refers to the base class `A`, so you cannot directly use these to access any members of the derived class.

In your simple example, you could simply keep hold of a pointer to `B` and use that:

```
std::shared_ptr<B> b = make_shared<B>();
b->b = 1;
v.push_back(b);
```

If you don't have access to the original pointer, then you will need some kind of polymorphism:

- use `static_cast<B*>(v.back().get())` **if** you know that all objects have type `B`
- use a virtual function or `dynamic_cast` (which requires the base class to contain a virtual function to work) if the objects might have different types

Answer (score 5):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    auto bptr = make_shared<B>();
    v.push_back(bptr);
    bptr->b = 1;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's correct, but The explanation of Mike Seymour helped me understand why.