# pass derived class shared_ptr as parameter to function that wants base class shared_ptr

Tags: c++, visual-c++, inheritance, shared-ptr

I've just through a massive refactoring of a project to add a base class in place of what is now a derived class of said base class (because I want more "types" of this class).

My problem is, some of the utility functions take a reference of the original class A as a shared_ptr and so a function declaration looks as follows:

```
void UtilityClass::func(shared_ptr<A> &a);
```

But now that I have the new base class B and A is derived from B (as well as a new class C which is derived from B) I'm getting a compile-time error when I try and pass an instance of A or C to the function whose declaration is now:

```
void UtilityClass::func(shared_ptr<B> &b);
```

If I try and pass:

```
shared_ptr<A> a;
utilclass.func(a);
```

I get a compile-time error saying that (paraphrase):

> Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to
>   'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>'

But I'm not sure how else I'd solve this problem, func() adds the A, B or C instance to a std::vector of shared_ptr values.

Thanks for your time.

EDIT: I also have another function that takes a reference so that it can assign a new instance of B to it and then return it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++11 smart pointers and polymorphism](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762176/c11-smart-pointers-and-polymorphism)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `shared_ptr<A> a;` to `shared_ptr<B> a;`
You can still assign it a pointer of the more derived type, but achieve polymorphism via the base class.

Comment: If I then pull the 'new' shared_ptr<A> back out of the vector at some point, do I dynamic_cast it back to shared_ptr<B> to use its functions again - is that supported?

Comment: Why does shared_ptr<A> already exist? You are probably doing it wrong. We could pull out pointers and shove them into different shared pointers and do all kinds of casts but your code will become a dangerous headache.

Comment: Sorry just edited my comment realizing it didn't make sense but I'm now realizing the part I left in doesn't make sense either :)

Thank you very much for the help - I think I get it now.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you're passing by non-`const` reference, which means you need the argument type to match exactly.

Change the function to take the pointer by value or `const` reference; then implicit conversions (such as `shared_ptr<Derived>` to `shared_ptr<Base>`) can be applied to the argument.

Answer (score 2):

The following works without any problems and is a supported scenario:

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <memory> 
#include <iostream>

class Foo { };

class Bar : public Foo { };

int _tmain() 
{
  std::shared_ptr<Bar> b(new Bar());

  std::cout << b.use_count() <<std::endl;

  std::shared_ptr<Foo> f(b);

  std::cout << b.use_count() <<std::endl;
  std::cout << f.use_count() <<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

If the classes are derived, no problems should occur.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {};
    virtual void print() {
        puts("A prints");
    }
};
class B: public A {
public:
    void print() {
        puts("B prints");
    }
};


void func(std::shared_ptr<A> a) {
    a->print();
}


int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<A> b_1(new B()); // can hold B*
    std::shared_ptr<B> b_2(new B());

    // both next function calls print "B prints"
    func(b_1);
    func(b_2); // can accept std::shared_ptr<B>
}
```