# reaseat shared_ptr<Derived> from function accepting shared_ptr<Derived>

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr, derived-class, base-class

I'm trying to reseat a `shared_ptr` of a derived class from a function that accept a `shared_ptr` of a base class.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17995219/5905016) is relevant, but it does not cover the fact that I need to reseat the pointer so a const reference cannot be used.

Here is a MWE:

```
#include <memory>

class A {
};

class B : public A {
};

class C {
 public:
 void doSomethingWithA(std::shared_ptr<A>& a){
     a = std::make_shared<B>();
 }
    
};

int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<B> b;
  C c;
  c.doSomethingWithA(b);
}
```

which gives the following compilation error:

```
 In function 'int main()':
21:23: error: no matching function for call to 'C::doSomethingWithA(std::shared_ptr<B>&)'
21:23: note: candidate is:
11:7: note: void C::doSomethingWithA(std::shared_ptr<A>&)
11:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<B>' to 'std::shared_ptr<A>&'
```

The reasoning behind the code is that there might be many derived classes and I know only at runtime which one is to be instantiated. The class `C` would decide to assign one of many derived types depending on what happens at runtime.

I didn't want to create several overloads of `doSomethingWithA()` and in general it is legal to assign a `shared_ptr` of a derived class to a `shared_ptr` of a base class, so I don't understand why the conversion is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert between these types with `std::static_pointer_cast` e.g.

```
#include <memory>

class A {
};

class B : public A {
};

class C {
public:
    void doSomethingWithA(std::shared_ptr<A>& a) {
        a = std::make_shared<B>();
    }

};

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
    C c;
    std::shared_ptr<A> a_ptr_from_b = std::static_pointer_cast<A>(b);
    c.doSomethingWithA(a_ptr_from_b);
}
```

There's also an `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` if you ever need that but in this case `static` will work.

Comment: After the static casting, would `b` still point to the same content?

Comment: yes, and the reference count will be two as it should be

Comment: Well, after the last line, `b` points to nullptr, and `a_ptr_from_b` points to the allocated object.  If that's what you want, great.